# React native iOS authorization header with Django rest framework

Tags: python, ios, django, react-native, django-rest-framework

has anyone encountered in DRF that the request from a react native app IOS Simulator is always been denied because of the Authorization header,
Basically, it doesn't accept my authorization header even if its correct and it is working fine on an android simulator and Insomnia.

I'm using a specific RetrieveAPIView for that, and the weird thing is I also have a ListAPIView that needs Authorization but that one is working fine on request from IOS simulator, Hoping that someone could help me here.

The solution I've made so far is:

Enabling all server on my accepted Django CORS setting.
Editing Info.plist file that allows the app to run or request even in local domains.
Pointing to my domain which has a valid SSL certificate.

But none of the above is working. thank you.

Comment: It would be benefitial if you posted the code that you have, so we can help you. Your RetrieveAPIView/ListAPIView

Comment: Did you fix this error?